# Emacs - Python: Run Configuration

Tags: python, emacs

I am using emacs24 with `python.el` (package shipped by emacs)

My workflow is usually the following:

1. Writing python code in `my_code.py`
2. Writing tests in `tests.py`
3. Execute tests from command line
4. Goto step 1

I would like to start the `tests.py` from shell without leaving emacs (or opening a shell buffer), to see the results and go on coding.

So far I could only find the possibility to run the `tests.py` script in buffer (`py-execute-buffer`). In this case, the interpreter ignores the `if __name__ == '__main__'` condition. Also there is no way to pass command line arguments.

Is there a way to define so called run-configurations, i.e.
"run file xy.py with n command line arguments and use the interpreter in path x/y/z" ?

Comment: I would put the command that you use to run tests in a Makefile. And use https://github.com/abo-abo/helm-make
to quickly select a make target without leaving the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general option is use to the `compile` command, you can pass it exact command you want to execute and it run the command and output the results in separate buffer. The errors are clickable so clicking on them will take you the test that failed. If can also wrap this in a custom command so that you will be able to run tests with just a keypress, but this of course depends on you workflow.

If you are using `nose` for testing then have a look at [nosemacs](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/nosemacs) which allows you to run nose tests from emacs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had a look into their code and it seems to use the `compile` command. Is there a convenient way to define multiple compile commands? (Like run configuration for tests and one for a call with parameters?)

Comment: I am not sure I understood you right, so this this maybe off the mark. When you do `M-x compile` it does ask for the commands to execute. Are you asking whether you can define custom commands so that you can directly run a given test_file (without entering the parameters again)?

Comment: Exactly, or something like different `M-x compile` and then in prompt enter `runconf` or `testconf` or `create-egg` ...

Comment: That is can be easy to hard to define in elisp, depending on you proficiency with elisp. I can help you if you give me an example of what you want to do in `runconf`, `testconf`. A template of such function is `(defun my-custom-command ()
  (interactive)
  (compile "<your-shell-command>"))`